# dereference * versus multiplication * ambiguity

Tags: c#

In the last line of Main(), I get an error for trying to do pointer stuff, but what I'm actually trying to do is invoke the multiplication operator I defined inside the Foo class. If that isn't the syntax for invoking the multiplication, what is?

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        class Foo
        {
            int foo;
            public Foo(int n)
            {
                foo = n;
            }
            public static object operator *(Foo a,Foo b)
            {
                return new Foo(a.foo * b.foo);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo a = new Foo(2);
            Foo b = new Foo(3);
            a * b;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but I don't see it.

Comment: You need to assign the result of the multiplication to something. You can't just put `a * b`. This will give the same error: `int x = 1; int y = 2; x * y;`

Comment: Perhaps assigning the result of the operator?

var result = a * b;

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably want `operator *` to return a `Foo`, not an `object`. That way, `a * b * c` will work too (rather than give an error about having no operator for `object` and `Foo`).

Comment: @Jereon Haha, it turns out that's not unrelated at all! I cut and pasted the override signature from an example somewhere, and forgot to change the return value. In the more substantial program where I first encountered the problem, I assigned the result of the multiplication to something, and didn't realize when posting this question that the error message I was getting when I did that was different from when I left it unassigned. Of course, the problem was that I was assigning an Object to a derived type. Stupid indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, the only expressions that can be used as statements (i.e. expressions which you can evaluate and simply ignore the result of the evaluation) are:

- **assignments**: `a = b;`

  - the most obvious valid statement, but even the assignment expression has a result value, which means you can write one-liners like `if ((a = b) == c) doStuff();` - so you are still "not using" the result of the assignment expression when doing a plain assignment
- **method calls**: `doStuff();`

  - even if `doStuff` returns a value, you can use it as a statement
  - if you call `a.ToString();` without storing the `string` anywhere, compiler won't complain
- **increments/decrements**: `i++;`, `i--;`

  - post/pre-increment result semantics are pretty much the same in all C-like languages, it doesn't matter if you use the result (as in `var x = i++;`) or not
- **awaiting on a method**: `await doAsyncStuff();`

  - you can await on an async operation without having to consume the result (this is basically analogous to plain method calls)
- **`new` object expressions**: `new Foo();`

  - even if you don't assign the newly instantiated object to anything, its constructor might do a number of things affecting the state of the program, as well as create static references to itself (otherwise it will just get collected)

So, since are not consuming the result of this operation (assigning it to a variable), C# compiler assumes you are trying to define a variable `b` of type `a*`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo a = new Foo(2);
    Foo b = new Foo(3);

    // this is seen by the compiler as "type* variable;"
    a * b;
}
```

This is why it gives you several compiler errors, like:

- `a` is a variable, but is being used as a type
- pointers are only allowed in an unsafe context

If you used a `+` operator, it wouldn't have mentioned any pointers, it would have just complained that you weren't supposed to use the expression as a statement, so it would probably make it more obvious.

To resolve the error, assign the result of the expression to a variable:

```
// type of `result` is an object, btw
var result = a * b;
```

As a side note, it would be wiser that your `operator *` method returns a result of type `Foo`, instead of a plain `object`:

```
public static Foo operator *(Foo a, Foo b) 
{
    ...
}

// type of `result` is now `Foo`, as it should be
Foo result = a * b;
```

Final suggestion would be that this concrete example is a good candidate for an immutable `struct`, instead of a `class` ([similar to the `Point` struct, for example](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Point.cs,a041be61667d4c9a)).

Comment: @m.rogalski: yes, I was just typing that, I only realized the `object` return type afterwards.

Comment: It turns out overlooking the fact that I was returning object instead of Foo was my entire problem. The rest is good to know for reference, though.